# How do I keep a clean recycle bin for organic material?

Tags: trash-can

Location is New Zealand, Christchurch, we have a green rubbish bin per household that takes organic rubbish, which is collected weekly.

In summer, flies always manage to get in and soon after maggots start to crawl out of it. I have been using fly spray every second day but I am wondering if there is a better way to prevent this explosion of flies and maggots?

One way I can think of is to:

- Every time after I dump food waste into it, I cover it up with a layer of lawn.

Thanks

Comment: Could you use compostable trash bags to seal it up better?

Comment: @isherwood, good idea, i will see if i can buy them somewhere

Comment: I love the name of your city; always have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively easy and cheap approach - which is used for the commercial compost bins where I work - is to have bin full of sawdust, and put a layer down before adding waste, and then cover each addition of waste.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your organic matter in a sealed bucket  and then only transfer it to the the green bin the nite before the collection day. Or you could build or buy a compost bin and put some of your organic matter in that and let the maggots do what they do, break it down into an excellent compost for gardening etc.

[HOW TO COMPOST FOOD SCRAPS](http://homecompostingmadeeasy.com/foodscraps.html)